# Return name of the Postgres database containing value in a row in a table

Tags: postgresql

I am looking for some implementation to essentially search the entire Postgres instance, all of it's databases to find the database containing a specific row in a specific table.

So I have a Postgres instance with 170 databases, every database has the exact same schema and table layout. In each database there is a specific table "SM_Project" and specific row "ProjectName" in said table. We have instances where we know a ProjectName or at least a partial match (can use LIKE with %) but we have no idea which database it lives in.

I am wanting to script, simplify the ability to enter a ProjectName and search the entire Postgres instance (all databases in there) and return the name of the db that contains that record.

I foolishly thought this would be a simple task, with my lack of experience I've tried to do this with several SELECT statements and while I can explicitly connect to a database and search for the record from there, I can't find a way to return the parent database name. I was thinking ti clunkily script it in bash to iterate through the databases until we get a true return on a EXISTS in a SELECT statement. But I feel like I'm overlooking something fundamental.

So my setup is like this"

- Postgres

  - db1

    - SM_Project

      - ProjectName
  - db2

    - SM_Project

      - ProjectName
  - db3

    - SM_Project

      - ProjectName

In short I'm looking to return the name of the database that contains a record of ProjectName equal to a string.

Any thoughts would be very welcomed!

Comment: Look into : https://stackoverflow.com/a/55269492/8843451

Comment: thanks @Sund'er that helps confirm my suspicions on handling this is in a one-liner query. I'll probably just connect to each DB to do a search.

Comment: if you know the connection string of each db , you can connect it from front end with loop and you can achieve the result you seek

Comment: @Sund'er That's the plan I think, although it seems rather tedious and inefficient.